# Origin of Sarveshaam Shanti Mantra

Tags: mantras

What is the origin of [Sarveshaam Shanti Mantra](http://www.hinduism.co.za/shanti.htm)

The text form of the mantra is as under:-

Om sarveshaam swastir bhavatu

Sarveshaam shantir bhavatu

Sarveshaam poornam bhavatu

Sarveshaam mangalam bhavatu

Sarve bhavantu sukhinah

Sarve santu niraamayaah

Sarve bhadraani pashyantu

Maakaschit duhkha bhaag bhavet

Meaning:-
Auspiciousness (swasti) be unto all; peace (shanti) be unto all;
fullness (poornam) be unto all; prosperity (mangalam) be unto all.
May all be happy! (sukhinah)
May all be free from disabilities! (niraamayaah)
May all look (pashyantu)to the good of others!
May none suffer from sorrow! (duhkha)

Shanti Mantras
By Sri Swami Sivananda
The Divine Life Society, Rishikesh

Comment: Must be from one of the Upanishads.

Comment: [THIS ARTICLE DOES A GOOD JOB AT EXPLAINING THE ORIGIN OF THE MANTRA BEAUTIFULLY](https://sampadanandamishra.medium.com/the-source-of-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%81-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%83-sarve-bhavantu-sukhina%E1%B8%A5-9023e23773a0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a peace mantra and the "inspiration" comes from the Brahadaranyaka Upanishad{ Khila division},though the mantra is not there in this exact form.

> Om asato maa satgamaya
>  Tamaso maa jyotir gamaya
>  Mrityor maa amritam
> gamaya
>
> > Meaning:
> >
> > Lead us from the unreal to the Real From darkness to Light
> > From death to Immortality

> Om poornamadah poornamidam Poornaat poornamudachyate 
> Poornasya
> poornamaadaya Poornamevaavashishyate
>
> > Meaning:
> >
> > That (pure consciousness) is full (perfect); this (the manifest universe of matter; of names and forms being maya) is full. This fullness has been projected from that fullness. When this fullness merges in that fullness, all that remains is fullness.

Reference is [Brahadaranyaka Upanishad](https://ia800500.us.archive.org/28/items/BrahadaranyakaUpanishad-ShankaraBhashya-English-SwamiMadhavaananda/BrahadaranyakaUpanishad-Madhavaananda.pdf)

---

**Therefore, to conclude:**

The following Popular Peace-Shanti Mantra:

> ॐ सर्वे भवन्तु सुखिनः 
> सर्वे सन्तु निरामयाः। 
> सर्वे भद्राणि पश्यन्तु
>  मा
> कश्चिद्दुःखभाग्भवेत।
>  ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः॥

###### The origin source of the above mantra, is untraceable as discussed in [this article](https://sampadanandamishra.medium.com/the-source-of-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%81-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%83-sarve-bhavantu-sukhina%E1%B8%A5-9023e23773a0) and [this article by ReSanskrit](https://resanskrit.com/sarve-bhavantu-sukhinah-the-peace-mantra/). It is said to have been loosely inspired from Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣhad & other pauranika texts.

Comment: I have checked the 12 main upanishads.Not seem to able to find the shanti mantra gven in the question.But the following page lists it among Veda/Upanishads mantras:http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/vedas-om_sarvesham_swastirvavatu.php

Comment: I have edited your answer with relevant material to make it more comprehensive, Conclusive and better readable for everyone.