# Where is mention of famous Mantra Sarve Sukhino Bhavantu in Scriptures?

Tags: identification-request

Where is this prayer mentioned? I checked in Shanti Mantras of Upanishads but couldn't find reference

> Sarve Bhavantu Sukhinah Sarve Santu Niramayah Sarve Bhadrani Pasyantu
> Ma Kaschid-Duhkha-Bhag-Bhavet
>
> May all be happy; May all be free from disabilities; May all behold
> what is auspicious; May none suffer from sorrow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Origin of Sarveshaam Shanti Mantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/origin-of-sarveshaam-shanti-mantra)

Comment: It doesnt @Vivikta

Comment: It does, the answer is simple: It's an interpolated Verse, with no origin to be found. Simply we cannot know the origin. [READ THIS](https://sampadanandamishra.medium.com/the-source-of-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%81-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%83-sarve-bhavantu-sukhina%E1%B8%A5-9023e23773a0)

Comment: Wonderful link. But since Uvata and Garuda Purana mention it, more or less we can say Hinduism has prayers to wish for welfare of all beings right

Comment: Yes, Religion prays the welfare of all beings - Definitely. It's sometimes the people (from all religion) - that desecrates these Supreme Ideals, ironically - in the name of "religion" only. However, even in recent history, one can see that Hinduism has been one of the peaceful religions.

Comment: This prayer is my foremost favorite prayer. There are variations from Garuda Purana and other puranic texts, but I don't know the origin or mention of it.